# What is wrong? Symmetric function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

I need some advice here.

What is  $y(\ln(4))$  if the function $y$ satisfies:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1-y^2$$
and is symmetric about the point $(\ln(9),0)$.

Solving that equation I end up with:

$$y=\frac{Ce^{2x}-1}{Ce^{2x}+1}.$$

And a function is symmetric about a point if $f(−x)=−f(x)\forall x.$

Plugging it into the equation:

$$y=\frac{Ce^{2(-\ln(9))}-1}{Ce^{2(-\ln(9))}+1} = -\frac{Ce^{2\ln(9)}-1}{Ce^{2\ln(9)}+1}. $$

(The constants shouldn't really matter here should they?)

Anyways:

$$\frac{15}{17} = \frac{Ce^{2\ln(4)}-1}{Ce^{2\ln(4)}+1}.$$

Which is wrong, and I guess the problem is the constants. How should i find them?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the constant $C = 1$.

And note that $$\frac{Ce^{2\ln(4)}-1}{Ce^{2\ln(4)}+1} =\frac{e^{\ln(4)^2}-1}{e^{\ln(4^2)}+1} =  = \frac{e^{16}-1}{e^{16}+1} = \frac{16 - 1}{16 + 1} = \frac{15}{17}$$

Answer (score 0):

In case when $\forall x f(-x)=-f(x)$ the function is symmetric about a point $(0;0)$

Comment: Aight, thanks. But how can I then determine whether it is symmetric about ln9?

Answer (score 0):

In general, a function is symmetric about $c$ if and only if $f(c+x) = f(c-x)$    (Check that this makes sense the intuitive idea of symmetry). Using the general solution for $y$, we obtain
$$ \frac{Ce^{2(\log(9)-x)}-1}{Ce^{2(\log(9)-x)}+1} = \frac{Ce^{2(\log(9)+x)}-1}{Ce^{2(\log(9)+x)}+1}$$
from which we can solve for our coefficient $C$.

Comment: Hmm, how can we find C when also x is unknown?

Comment: If $y(x)$ as stated is a solution, then $C$ should be independent of $x$. Thus, we could plug in a convenient value of $x$ (say, $log(9)$) and use that to solve for $C$. Alternatively, we could simply rearrange the equation algebraically to find $C$; this may seem to give $C$ as a function of $x$ but as I argued before, that function must be a constant.